# join two pyspark dataframe based on matching value(upto certain decimal point)

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two dataframe in pyspark:
df1

```
+-------+--------+----------------+-------------+                               
|new_lat|new_long|        lat_long|   State_name|
+-------+--------+----------------+-------------+
|  33.64| -117.63|[33.64,-117.625] |STATE 1     |
|  23.45| -101.54|[23.45,-101.542] |STATE 2     |
+-------+--------+----------------+-------------+
```

df2

```
+---------+-----+--------------------+----------+------------+
|    label|value|            dateTime|       lat|        long|
+---------+-----+--------------------+----------+------------+
|msg      |  437|2019-04-06T05:10:...|33.6436263|-117.6255508|
|msg      |  437|2019-04-06T05:10:...|33.6436263|-117.6255508|
|msg      |  437|2019-04-06T05:10:...| 23.453622|-101.5423864|
|msg      |  437|2019-04-06T05:10:...| 23.453622|-101.5420964|
```

I want to join these two tables based on matching lat,long value upto 2 decimal. So the output dataframe I want is:

df3

```
+---------+-----+--------------------+----------+------------+------+
|    label|value|            dateTime|       lat|        long|state |
+---------+-----+--------------------+----------+------------+-------
|msg      |  437|2019-04-06T05:10:...|33.6436263|-117.6255508|STATE 1
|msg      |  437|2019-04-06T05:10:...|33.6436263|-117.6255508|STATE 1
|msg      |  437|2019-04-06T05:10:...| 23.453622|-101.5423864|STATE 2
|msg      |  437|2019-04-06T05:10:...| 23.453622|-101.5420964|STATE 2
```

How can I do this in an efficient way considering df2 has more than 100M rows.

I tried with `df3=df1.join(df2, df1. new_lat == df2. lat, 'left')` but not sure how can I consider upto two decimal in df1

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ScootCork I tried with this one but not sure how to consider upto 2 decimal in join statement `df3 = df1.join(df2, df1. new_lat == df2. lat, 'left')`

Comment: I guess the most direct approach is to round the `df2.lat` column to two decimal places and then join on that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substring` is definitely the easiest implementation, but won't always give you the accuracy that you might require (think int rounding on 0.5).

To get better accuracy you can just use a quick filter:

```py
threshold = 0.01

df3 = (
    df1
    .join(df2)
    .filter(df1.new_lat - threshold < df2.lat)
    .filter(df2.lat < df1.new_lat + threshold)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`substring`** in your join condition.

```
df3=df1.join(df2, df1.new_lat == substring(df2.lat,1,5), 'left')
```